# Showing that a transformation in a finite planar region determines a bijection

Tags: integration

Sketch the finite planar region D which is contained in the positive quadrant $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ and bounded by the four curves

$$y=x^{1/3} ,\ y=\frac{{x^{1/3}}}{4} ,\,y=x,\, y=\frac{{x}}{4}$$

Show that the transformation given by

$$ u=\frac{{y}}{x^{1/3}},\, v=\frac{{y}}{x} $$
determines a bijection between $(0,\infty)^2 \,and \, (0,\infty)^2 $. Evaluate

$$\iint_Dx^{-4/3}dxdy.$$

I sketched the region and found the area needed but am  unsure how to determine the bijection and thus solve the integral.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:(0,\infty)^2 \rightarrow (0,\infty)^2$ as $f(x,y) = (u,v)$. We want to prove that $f$ is a bijection.

**$f$ is an injection:**
\begin{align} 
&f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2) = (u,v) \\ 
\Leftrightarrow & \ \left(\frac{y_1}{x_1^{1/3}} = \frac{y_2}{x_2^{1/3}}\right)\wedge\left(\frac{y_1}{x_1} = \frac{y_2}{x_2}\right) \\ 
\Rightarrow & \ \left(\left(\frac{y_1}{x_1^{1/3}}.\frac{x_1}{y_1}\right) = \left(\frac{y_2}{x_2^{1/3}}.\frac{x_2}{y_2}\right)\right) \\ &\text{[Dividing 1st equation by the 2nd. This is valid because none of the terms are }0\text{.]} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \ x_1^{2/3} = x_2^{2/3} \ \Leftrightarrow x_1 = x_2 \ \text{[Both }x_1\text{and }x_2\text{are positive reals.]} \\
\Rightarrow & \ y_1 = y_2 \left[\frac{y_1}{x_1} = \frac{y_2}{x_2}, x_1>0, x_2>0 \right]\\ 
\Rightarrow & \ \left(y_1 = y_2 \right)\wedge\left(x_1 = x_2 \right) \ \Rightarrow (x_1,y_1) = (x_2, y_2) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare
\end{align} 
**$f$ is a surjection:**
\begin{align}
& \forall (u,v) \in (0,\infty)^2 \\
& \frac{u}{v} \in (0, \infty) \  \Rightarrow \ \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{3/2} \in (0,\infty). \ \text{Take} \ x = \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{3/2}\\
& \frac{u^3}{v} \in (0, \infty) \  \Rightarrow \ \left(\frac{u^3}{v}\right)^{1/2} \in (0,\infty). \ \text{Take} \ y = \left(\frac{u^3}{v}\right)^{1/2} \\
\end{align}
Then, $(x,y) \in (0,\infty)^2$, $f(x,y) = (u,v). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$

Take $D$ to be open. $D \subset (0,\infty)^2$.
Describe now $\widetilde{D}$ as the open planar region in $(0,\infty)^2$ bounded by $u = 1$, $u = \dfrac{1}{4}$, $v = 1$, $v = \dfrac{1}{4}$.
It is easy to see that, under this transformation, $D \mapsto \widetilde{D}$. $x^{-4/3}$ can be written as $\dfrac{v^2}{u^2}$. Now, the integral can be calculated on the open rectangle $\widetilde{D}$ rather easily (use **Fubini**) by the given transformation.